# Grails 3 schema-export wrong user name or passowrd

Tags: grails, schemaexport

I have a Grails 3 project with multiple data sources in Intellij. Try to run the Grails command:

```
schema-export  --filename grails-app/conf/db/migration/operator/ddl.sql  --datasource=operator
```

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-194]

The full error is below. Interestingly, the connection is not to an h2 DB. application.yml is using a PostgreSQL DB.

```
dataSources:
  dataSource:
    pooled: false
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: user1
    password: password1
    dialect: net.kaleidos.hibernate.PostgresqlExtensionsDialect
  operator:
    pooled: false
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: user2
    password: password2
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresqlExtensionsDialect

environments:
  development:
    server:
        contextPath: '/@info.app.name@'
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: none
        url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?currentSchema=schema1
    datasources:
        operator:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost1:5432/mydb?currentSchema=schema2
```

Why is this failing?

> Generating script to .\build\ddl.sql in environment 'development' for
>   DataSource 'operator' 2017-06-08 14:35:14.598 ERROR --- [
>   Thread-13] o.g.p.d.EmbeddedDatabaseShutdownHook     : Error shutting
>   down datasource
>
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Wrong user name or password [28000-194]
>     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
>     at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)     at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)  at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)  at
>   org.h2.engine.Engine.validateUserAndPassword(Engine.java:336)     at
>   org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:162)    at
>   org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:137)   at
>   org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:27)    at
>   org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:354)   at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:116)   at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.(JdbcConnection.java:100)    at
>   org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:69)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:159)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugins.datasource.EmbeddedDatabaseShutdownHook.shutdownEmbeddedDatabase(EmbeddedDatabaseShutdownHook.groovy:87)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1218)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:925)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:908)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:76)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugins.datasource.EmbeddedDatabaseShutdownHook$_stop_closure2.doCall(EmbeddedDatabaseShutdownHook.groovy:39)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1027)
>     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)   at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2030)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2015)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2056)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugins.datasource.EmbeddedDatabaseShutdownHook.stop(EmbeddedDatabaseShutdownHook.groovy:38)
>     at
>   org.grails.plugins.datasource.EmbeddedDatabaseShutdownHook.stop(EmbeddedDatabaseShutdownHook.groovy:62)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:231)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$300(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.stop(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:365)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.stopBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onClose(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:120)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$2.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:928)

Answer (score 0):

I partly solved this. The Grails 3 documentation for configuring multiple data sources appears to be wrong. http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources   It doesn't appear to work for the per-environment configuration in application.yml. By putting all the configuration parameters at the root level the export-schema command runs.

Which answers the question I asked here, but the schema-export still doesn't work:

- It creates build\ddl.sql (the gradle schemaExport default), not the one specified on the schema-export grails command
- build/ddl.sql is empty.

Comment: It looks like this documentation is just rubbish http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/schema-export.html

Comment: There is an "Improve this doc" link. Click it if you think improvements can be made instead of complaining online. At the minimum create a Github issue explaining why the documentation is "rubbish"